# In a PickerView with two rows, how select one row and charge the second row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

I need something with this

```
NSMutableArray *foodArray;

NSMutableArray *ingredientsArray;

[foodArray addObject:Pizza];
```

and when select Pizza in a PickerView show me in the second row ingredientsArray for the pizza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you'll need to make sure that you've implemented

`- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component`

once that is done you'll need to update the data that is driving your UIPickerView whenever a new row is selected in the first component, then call `reloadComponent:` on the picker view, passing in the component (in this case 1).